# contact.save is not a function error while using [mongoose_model_object].save() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Here auth is a middleware that is generating jwt and authorizing user, and I have a mongoose model named Contact. However when I try to do contact.save() it throws me an exception as a contact.save() is not a function.

```
router.post('/',auth,async (req,res)=>{
try
{
 let contact = new Contact();
 contact = {...req.body};
 contact.userID=req.user.id;

 const {error} = validateContact(contact);
 console.log(`ERROR - ${error}`);

 if(error){
  return res.status(400).json({"status":1,"message":error.details[0].message});
 } 

 const contact1 = await contact.save();

 res.status(200).json({"status":0,"message":"contact addedd","contact":contact1});
}
catch(error){
console.log(`contacts - ${error.message}`);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.save()` is available on an instance of mongoose [Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save). By running `contact = {...req.body};` you are replacing such instance with a new plain JavaScript object so you're loosing that function.

You can pass `req.body` as a constructor parameter instead:

```
let contact = new Contact(req.body);
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer it did solve the issue...kudos

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the value of the model Contact when you say

```
 let contact = new Contact();

 //Here is the problem----

 contact = {...req.body}; //<------------

 //-----------------------

 contact.userID=req.user.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter into the constructor like that:

```
let contact = new Contact(..req.body)
```

Comment: why only two dots? `..req.body`